# Drawing rectangle with border only in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I found the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013781/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-over-a-specific-region-in-a-matplotlib-graph):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
someX, someY = 0.5, 0.5
plt.figure()
currentAxis = plt.gca()
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((someX - .1, someY - .1), 0.2, 0.2,alpha=1))
plt.show()
```

Which gives:
[image]

But what I want is a rectangle with only a blue border and inside of it to be transparent. How can I do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You just need to set the `facecolor` to the string 'none' (not the python `None`)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
someX, someY = 0.5, 0.5
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
currentAxis = plt.gca()
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((someX - 0.1, someY - 0.1), 0.2, 0.2,
                      alpha=1, facecolor='none'))
```

Comment: Thanks. There is also a parameter called 'filled'

Comment: @Naji N.B.: `fill` is expecting a boolean; so you could keep `fill=True` and still get a hollow rectangle with `facecolor='none'` in the case that you were looping through different colors and `'none'` was one of them.

Comment: For reference: [matplotlib.patches.Rectangle API](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle).

Answer (score 28):

You should set the `fill=None`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

someX, someY = 0.5, 0.5
plt.figure()
currentAxis = plt.gca()
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((someX - .1, someY - .1), 0.2, 0.2, fill=None, alpha=1))
plt.show()
```

[image]