# Printing one color using imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, rgb, imshow

I want to print a color on the screen using RGB values and the output should be just a single color. For example if I give RGB values of red, I want the output to show me a red color. But when I try this code, it isn't working. What am I missing?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow([(255, 0, 0)])
plt.show()
```

The output is:[image: plot output]

Comment: Hi there, The imshow command will display an image on your screen by normalizing the values in the array. So your array [255,0,0] is normalized to (1,0,0). These values are then displayed as 3 pixels  according to the default colormap: yellow at 0 and violet at 1 and 2 on the x axis. I suggest you look at the [gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) in matplotlib to find an example of what you are trying to do and modify the code as you need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to display a 2D color array with `1` row and `3` columns. The pixel values from left to right are `255`, `0`and `0`. As @Ben K. correctly pointed out in the comments, by doing so the intensity values are scaled to the range 0..1 and displayed using the current colormap.  That's why your code displays one yellow pixel and two violet pixels.

If you wish to specify the RGB values **you should create a 3D array** of `m` rows, `n` columns and `3` color channels (one chromatic channel for each RGB component).

## Demo

The snippet below generates a random array of indices of a color palette and displays the result:

```
In [14]: import numpy as np

In [15]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [16]: from skimage import io

In [17]: palette = np.array([[255,   0,   0], # index 0: red
    ...:                     [  0, 255,   0], # index 1: green
    ...:                     [  0,   0, 255], # index 2: blue
    ...:                     [255, 255, 255], # index 3: white
    ...:                     [  0,   0,   0], # index 4: black
    ...:                     [255, 255,   0], # index 5: yellow
    ...:                     ], dtype=np.uint8)
    ...: 

In [18]: m, n = 4, 6

In [19]: indices = np.random.randint(0, len(palette), size=(4, 6))

In [20]: indices
Out[20]: 
array([[2, 4, 0, 1, 4, 2],
       [1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 0],
       [4, 4, 3, 3, 0, 4],
       [2, 5, 0, 5, 2, 3]])

In [21]: io.imshow(palette[indices])
Out[21]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0xdbb8ac8>
```

[image: color pixels]

You could also generate a random color pattern rather than using a color palette:

```
In [24]: random_colors = np.uint8(np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(m, n, 3)))

In [24]: random_colors
Out[27]: 
array([[[137,  40,  84],
        [ 42, 142,  25],
        [ 48, 240,  90],
        [ 22,  27, 205],
        [253, 130,  22],
        [137,  33, 252]],

       [[144,  67, 156],
        [155, 208, 130],
        [187, 243, 200],
        [ 88, 171, 116],
        [ 51,  15, 157],
        [ 39,  64, 235]],

       [[ 76,  56, 135],
        [ 20,  38,  46],
        [216,   4, 102],
        [142,  60, 118],
        [ 93, 222, 117],
        [ 53, 138,  39]],

       [[246,  88,  20],
        [219, 114, 172],
        [208,  76, 247],
        [  1, 163,  65],
        [ 76,  83,   8],
        [191,  46,  53]]], dtype=uint8)

In [26]: io.imshow(random_colors)
Out[26]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0xe6c6a90>
```

[image: random color pattern]

Answer (score 4):

This is the output produced by

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow([(3,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,1)])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: imshow plot]

You see that the three tuples I provided to `imshow` are interpreted as rows of a matrix:

```
 3  0  0 
 0  2  0
 0  0  1
```

The numeric values are mappped to colors for the plot. The `colorbar` function shows the mapping between colors and numeric values.

To draw rectangles, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445449/3082472), but replace the value of the `facecolor` parameter with one of the following possibilities:

- [A color name](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html), as a string.
- [A Hex color code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet), given as a string with a leading `#` sign. For example, `facecolor='#FF0000'` is bright red.
- A triple with three values between 0 and 1, which specify the (Red, Green, Blue) parts of your color. (*Not 0 to 255 like you assumed in your question!*)

Use the `edgecolor` parameter in the same manner to determine the color of the rectangle border, or use `'None'` to draw no border.