# How to convert hsv to rgb in python?

Tags: python, image, colors, rgb, hsv

I don't know why, but it doesn't work.

I've tried the following code:

```py
matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb([[[220 / 255, 255 / 255, 255 / 255]]])

matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb([[[(220 % 360) / 255, 255 / 255, 255 / 255]]])

matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb([[[220, 255, 255]]])

# same with
cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8([[[120, 255, 255]]]), cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```

but when I plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(converted_color)
plt.show()
```

It's showing some random stuff

getting values from `GIMP`:

[image: values from GIMP]

---

final result

```py
h, s, v = 270, 100, 100
r, g, b = np.multiply((colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h/360, s/100, v/100)), 255)
crop[mask == 0] = [r, g, b]
```

**ex e len t!**

---

here is fixed cv2 solution. h - having 180 maximum. opencv as usual doing thing on his own way... -___-

```py
h, s, v = 270, 100, 100
r, g, b = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8([[[h / 2, (s/100)*255, (v/100)*255]]]), cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)[0][0]
crop[mask == 0] = [r, g, b]
```

Comment: why 3 consecutive `[` ? The function expect an array-like object, so one is enough, and probably less confusing to matplotlib, about your intensions. It seems it doesn't matter. In any casem the second example: just divide by 360. The third: values should be in range 0 to 1

Comment: it's part of the np.uint8() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using colorsys:

```
import colorsys
colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.4)
```

Output:

```
(0.2, 0.4, 0.4)
```

**Edit**

An example could be:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import colorsys

h, s, v = 0.83, 1.0, 0.50
#RGB from 0 to 1 NO from 0 to 255
r, g, b = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)
print(r, g, b)

rect1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((-200, -100), 400, 200, color=[r, g, b])
plt.axes().add_patch(rect1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To see why you may be having troubles in displaying color using imshow refer to: [Printing one color using imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497352/printing-colors-on-screen-in-python)

Comment: Purple in hsv is (0.83, 1.0, 0.50) and in rgb is (0.50, 0.0, 0.50)  @Oleg

Comment: For RGB in "255 format" just multiply by 255  -> (128, 0, 128) @Oleg

Comment: awesome! r, g, b = np.multiply((colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)), 255) - just one more thing - is there way to change input range from 0-1 to 0-360 ?

Comment: Multiplying with 360? It is just scaling. Note: most programs requires angles from 0 to 1

Comment: dividing right!! fiiiinaaalllyyy oh gooood, it was extremely hard, thank you @MateoLara

Comment: and @Giacomo Catenazzi