# Create shape using hlines, vlines with matplotlib so that the exterior corners are complete

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

Example code:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.vlines(x=0.6, ymin=0.2, ymax=0.8, linewidth=10)
ax.hlines(y=0.2, xmin=0.2, xmax=0.6, linewidth=10)
ax.hlines(y=0.8, xmin=.6, xmax=0.8, linewidth=10)
ax.vlines(x=0.8, ymin=0.8, ymax=1.1, linewidth=10)
ax.hlines(y=1.1, xmin=.5, xmax=0.8, linewidth=10)
ax.vlines(x=0.5, ymin=0.4, ymax=1.1, linewidth=10)
ax.hlines(y=.4, xmin=.2, xmax=0.5, linewidth=10)
```

Which produces:

[image]

In the corners are gaps though, whereas I would like these to be flush.

To be clear, the corners currently look like:

[image]

Whereas I would like them to look like:

[image]

# Edit

Side note - if there's just a rectangle to be created the following can be used:

```py
import matplotlib.patches as pt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
frame = pt.Rectangle((0.2,0.2),0.4,0.6, lw=10,facecolor='none', edgecolor='k') 
ax.add_patch(frame)
```

More info on the edit here:

- [How to draw a rectangle over a specific region in a matplotlib graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013781/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-over-a-specific-region-in-a-matplotlib-graph)
- [matplotlib: how to draw a rectangle on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image)
- [Drawing rectangle with border only in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445005/drawing-rectangle-with-border-only-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from plotting the lines as one segmented curve, an idea is to put a scatter dot at the start and end of each line segment. The size of a scatter dot is measured quadratic; a line width of 10 corresponds to a scatter size of about 70.  Matplotlib also supports [`capstyle='round'`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_enums_api.html#matplotlib._enums.CapStyle), which starts and ends the lines with a rounded cap. (For `ax.plot`, the parameter is named `solid_capstyle='round', while for` ax.vlines`it is just`capstyle='round').`

Other allowed values for `capstyle` are `'projecting'` (extending the line with half its thickness) and `'butt'` (stops the lines at the end point).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 4))
for ax, capstyle in zip(axs, ['round', 'projecting', 'butt']):
    ax.vlines(x=0.6, ymin=0.2, ymax=0.8, linewidth=10, capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.hlines(y=0.2, xmin=0.2, xmax=0.6, linewidth=10, capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.hlines(y=0.8, xmin=.6, xmax=0.8, linewidth=10, capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.vlines(x=0.8, ymin=0.8, ymax=1.1, linewidth=10, capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.hlines(y=1.1, xmin=.5, xmax=0.8, linewidth=10, capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.vlines(x=0.5, ymin=0.4, ymax=1.1, linewidth=10, capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.hlines(y=.4, xmin=.2, xmax=0.5, linewidth=10, capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.set_title(f"capstyle='{capstyle}'")
plt.show()
```

[image: line segments using round cap style]

Comment: thanks - the corners are rounded on this rather than square as in the image, but it's still useful... Is it possible to get the corners square ?

Comment: You can use `capstyle='projecting'`, which extends the line with half of the thickness.  This works well when the segments are in angles of 90 degrees. See updated answer.